# Can you run Fiber between two different types of switches?

Tags: fiber

We are looking into adding a 10g fiber link between two of our locations however we arent sure if its possible. We have an HP Procurve 2910al on one side and an AdTran 1638 on the other and we are looking to go between with single mode fiber.

If we get the appropriate SFP adapters for either side does it matter if one SFP adapter is Adtran and the other is HP?

Comment: When you say *two locations* I suppose you planned for the right mode for the distance

Comment: Yes we are planning on using single mode even though the distance is such that multi mode would work just fine. (we are talking two buildings right next door to each other)

Answer (score 23):

Yes, this technique is used all of the time on switch to switch communication. The underlying protocol is the same. It's the Switch and SFP's job to convert to this common layer 1 protocol.

Comment: There are open standards for 10g, so switches are intended to be interoperable when connected. Definitely works!

Comment: You should avoid switch to switch communication over long distance. You'd better have two routers and split your broadcast domain in two. It would reduce the impact of a layer 2 issues and will make your network less flat.

Comment: From what i've read this is the case. So long as your switches support the same fiber standards you're good to go. And definitely get the right SFP hardware for each so you don't run into any problems with either end's negotiations. I have heard horror stories if you go cheap and get ones that don't work you might be tracing that issue down for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

In switch to switch communication, if the switches and SFPs go in accordance with the fiber specifications, there should be no issues. Certainly, if the switch or SFPs are of low quality, then network problems occur.